# SAML Single Logout for Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, saml, single-logout

I'm trying to implement single logout for SAML in keycloak and the documentation doesn't mention this properly and is confusing. I was looking for exact steps on how to implement it. So far, what i have done is:

Generate the logout request payload, base64 encode it, url encode it and send it to the logout url as a param. Assume that the realm name is `Abc`

```
http://auth-server/auth/realms/Abc/protocol/saml?SAMLRequest={encodedSAMLRequest}
```

The saml payload is

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="random uuid" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-02-09T06:53:26Z" Destination="ip-address:8443/auth/realms/Abc/protocol/saml">
  <saml:Issuer>https://ip-address:8443/auth/realms/Abc</saml:Issuer>
  <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">user-email@abc.com</saml:NameID>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

However, while sending this, i get 400 error saying "Unknown login requestor"
(eventhough I want to logout)

The site [here](https://www.samltool.com/validate_logout_req.php) says the request is valid. Maybe I am missing some extra parameter or something? I would also need an exact way to send. I have to use scala. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your Issuer might be wrong.
It looks like your issuer is a Keycloak URI, but it is supposed to be a URI representing your application (service provider). It is the same as the client ID field of your configured SAML client in the Keycloak admin gui

Comment: thanks. I figured that out quite late. Also had to make some changed for the client in the admin gui and it worked!